# Where do I publish a program?

Tags: applications

I have finished designing a little application for Pandora and I am not sure how I can get it out and share it with everyone. What should I do to help advertise it to the public and let other people use it? As of right now it is free, and I hope to keep it that way, so I don't want to spend any money to give it out. I had actually designed this application just for personal use, but hey, why should I be the only one to use it?

Comment: There are many options. I'll just suggest one that I use, [Google code hosting](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A few of the more popular options.

- [Github](https://github.com/)
- [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/)
- [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org)
- [LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/)
- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.com)
- [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) (generally speaking, only .Net projects)

Personally I'd recommend github over the others, and it's become very popular in the last 12 months.

Most of these options will allow you to set up some sort of wiki, blog, or static pages to provide more info on your project, this is a good idea if you need to provide tutorials / getting started info etc.

For example, github has it's [pages](https://github.com/blog/272-github-pages) feature, and if your code root has a README file it will be shown on your project homepage, call it README.md it will be rendered as Markdown, a few other [formats are supported](https://github.com/github/markup).

Comment: Add bitbucket.org and launchpad.org at least to be more DSVC agnostic...

Comment: added, good call.

Comment: I'm thinking launchpad.org should actually be launchpad.net

Answer (score 3):

Your program serves some purpose, so an internet forum about the topic might be the right place to announce it. Becuase that's where the people who might be interested in your program can be expected.

For example, many years ago I wrote a controller plugin for playstation emulations, so I announced it at a forum about emulation.

Comment: +1 Yep, initial announcements should definitely be made on forums where the program is relevant, but try hard not to be spammy!

Comment: +1 A Pandora specific forum would be the obvious place to start. Does pandora have user founded Groups like last.fm?

Answer (score 2):

> A simple **Blog**.

Free, standard & [easy to setup](http://www.blogger.com).

I assume you are not building an open source application as you don't mention it in your question.

If your application is open source and you are looking for contributors or willing to share the source code, check this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33028/where-do-i-publish-a-program/33041#33041).

Comment: +1 for not assuming the software is open source, although I'm not sure a blog is the best solution here.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [GitHub](https://github.com/) for my smaller personal projects. A lot of it will come down to what type of source code management you have. If you don't use something to manage your code, start now. Having you source for everyone to see is a good thing though. If someone comes along likes what you made, but has an idea of something they want to add, they just download the source code, add what they want, and ask you to integrate it to the original. Your application is then improved for others to use!

As Keith said, Google Code would also be a wonderful choice.